Old school sci-fi book about descendants on a generational spacecraft
I'm looking for the name of a sci-fi book based on a generational spacecraft that sent heavy rain (radioactive isotopes) to Earth because they were angry, then later sent a message to Earth warning them about heavy rain and also apologizing.

This is  likely Starburst by Frederic Pohl.
The particles are kaons radiation which causes all nuclear material on Earth into a heat meltdown.
If so then it's been asked in here a few times
